# Python - How do I keep returning values from a function with a while statement?

Tags: python, function, while-loop, return

So, the code outlined below sends arguments to a function I've created called *bsearch* and I want the function *main()* to send the arguments with the key argument scaled down by 1 from 11 (11,10,9,8,7...) until it reaches 0 an I want the value count outputted each time --- currently it only returns the first count. How do I get it to return after each while loop?

```
def main():
    ilist = [x+1 for x in range(10)]
    key = 11
    start = 0
    end = 10
    while key > 0:
        count = b(ilist,key,start,end)
        key = key -1
        return count
```

Comment: try to use generators and make use of the `yield` keyword

Comment: using a `return` statement exits the current `def` block of your code so after the first iteration of the while loop, the code stops running

Comment: to use yield is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to look at a few tutorials but I imagine you want something like this:

```
def main():
    count_list = []
    for x in range(1,11):
        count_list.append(bsearch(x))  # append your results to a list
    return count_list  # return out of the scope of the loop
```

or using a list comprehension as suggested in the comments:

```
def main():
    return [bsearch(x) for x in range(1,11)]
```

Comment: You could also use a list comprehension to make it even shorter.

return [ bsearch(x) for x in range(1,11) ]